# WebTarget Bean instantiation failing in Spring while calling the contained class method through CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, completable-future

I am calling different other web services from my spring boot application. To increase the performance rather than calling them sequentially I wanted to implement `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` to have an asynchronous execution.

The services which i am calling, some of them are internal and some are external. Therefore, for internal I am directly calling their api interfaces which are present in maven dependency  and for external ones i am using `javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget`

While implementing the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` call the client classes which are internal gets executed successfully while those which have `WebTarget` as `@Inject` dependency fails as the `scopedTarget.XXService_nameXX_wt` bean is not created.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.charityserv_wt': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget]: Factory method 'target' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.coreContext': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread
```

Calling code:

```
CompletableFuture<SearchResult> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> searchServiceClientImpl.getsearchSearchRequest(encryptedAccountNumber));
```

ServiceClientClass:

```
@Component
public class SearchServiceClientImpl{

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchServiceClientImpl.class);


    @Inject
    @EndPoint(service = "searchserv")
    private WebTarget searchserv;


    /**  
    @Inject
    @EndPoint(service = "searchserv")
    private SearchResource searchserv;
    **/ 

    public Response buildsearchRequest(String payerId) throws WebApplicationException , IllegalArgumentException,ProcessingException {

        Response response = null;   
        String apiUrl = "path/url";

        response = searchserv.path(apiUrl).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();        

        return response;
    }

    public SearchSearchResult getsearchSearchRequest(String encryptedAccountNumber){

        SearchSearchResult SearchSearchResult = null;   
        Response response = null;

        try{
            response = buildSearchRequest(encryptedAccountNumber);

            if (null == response){ 
                return null;
            } 
            if(response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {                 
                SearchSearchResult = response.readEntity(SearchSearchResult.class);
            } 

        return SearchSearchResult;
    }
```

The dependency injection `SearchResource searchserv` which is mentioned in comments works but WebTarget causes this exception. Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: How is it resolved? @Ankit